# DataMapper Gem - Join two tables which are belongs to different repositories

Tags: ruby

I am using DataMapper gem (http://datamapper.org/) and I need to join two tables which are belongs to two different repositories.

Models are:

- Visit Model - Tracking repository - table name - visits
- Click Model - Google repository - table name - clicks

we have a option in DataMapper like below to join two tables from same repository if these two models has a association like-

```
Visit.all(Visit.clicks.status => 'open')
```

I tried to join using sql query:

```
DataMapper.repository.adapter.query("
    SELECT v.* FROM tracking.visits AS v 
    INNER JOIN google.clicks AS c ON c.uuid = v.uuid")
```

But it's throwing me an error:

> tracking.visits table not exits.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: *"tracking.visits table does not exist."* -- What tables exist? What is your database schema? My guess is that the table is called `trackings`, not `tracking`.

Comment: @TomLord Thanks for your reply.
No 'tracking' is the name of the repository in DM, in general we can say schema name. Table name is visits.